# Small Line Inserted into Sharelatex

Tags: line-breaking

I'm trying to figure out how to insert a small straight and horizontal line segment into a Sharelatex text file. Any ideas?

Comment: `\rule{2cm}{0.1cm}`?

Comment: Actually, some more context would be nice.

Comment: What is "small"? May be `-`, or  `--`, or even  `---` ?